# Drop-down menus are not presented in slider menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, position, angular-ui-bootstrap

I got one really annoying bug, that I couldn't find an answer for. I have a menu slider that has a drop-down menu attached to each item. The slider itself is custom made, but the drop-downs functionality is provided by UI-Bootstrap.

Here is a simple fiddle, that I've made to get more about the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lus92rqm/7/

If you can see in the CSS tab, I've added some comments about where I think the problem comes from and a possible solution that I ran into. So basically, all the thing is not working because of the `overflow: hidden` style attached to the `.menu-slider-wrapper`. I needed it though, because I want to hide all the items that are not in the visible area - the `570px` width of this container.

I also tried to add `position: fixed` to the `.dropdown-menu` class and thought it was working perfectly, until I tried to scroll the page down... The shown menu is scrolling with the page which is not the behavior I'm searching for.

One more thing is that I definitely need a `position: relative` attached to `.menu-slider` class, because in that way I can move the slider from left to right and opposite - changing the `left` property of it.

Sooo, anyone with any ideas how I can manage to workout this thing?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dropdown-append-to-body, see the [example](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown) on the docs page.

Comment: I tried it actually, but the menu is still not showing.
However, it's showing on different position, I think it's still depending on the overflow from it's parents...